# A Computer Virus which doesn't damage your PC

Tags: terminology, antonyms, synonyms

I am a developer from Italy, and because I usually work with English people, I need to know some new words.

What do you call a 'Computer Virus' which is only annoying but not dangerous?

Comment: It depends what it does and how it was transferred onto the computer. I suggest you do a quick search on the following words: malware, spyware, Trojans, and worms.

Comment: It is a batch file generated with a software. It only create fake tmp file on the desktop. How can I call one of this?

Comment: I think you can just call it a [prank virus](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Prank-Virus-%28Windows%29).

Comment: Hi Otto. There is quite a big problem with the terminology involved in this question. Just briefly - A  computer virus is a specific kind of computer program that a) reproduces it self, and b) modifies it self. However, the term is often used to describe any kind of software which is intended to cause harm to your computer (_malware_ is a more appropriate term here). Which of these usages are you using?

Comment: There's prankware, adware, ransomware, spyware, malware... But I don't think there's a term for what you want. There's no term which specifically means "does no harm". In part because, of course, arguably the fact that it's sapping clock cycles and taking up drive space is harm. What counts as "dangerous" depends on the person.

Comment: Also, @dwjohnston, you're wrong about that definition. The **only** defining characteristic of a virus is that it copies itself. If it also modifies itself, it's called "polymorphic". The first viruses didn't modify themselves at all. And a virus which spreads via networks is, of course, called a "worm".

Answer (score 3):

A **benign** virus does no harm.

[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/benign):

> (Of a tumour) not malignant:
>   *benign growths*

Answer (score 1):

One generic term used for (relatively) nonharmful but unwelcome apps and files that sneak or hitchhike onto a person's computer, often on the coattails of a desired program or download, is **potentially unwanted program (PUP)**. AVG (an antivirus company) [describes PUPs](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlname=What-is-Potentially-Unwanted-Program-PUP) this way:

> Potentially Unwanted Programs sometimes act very similarly to viruses or spyware. They are usually installed legitimately as a part of another program (often designed as an "AD-Supported program" – in which the End User License Agreement typically prompts the user to accept that, in addition to the desired program, an additional program will also be installed).

Another very common term for unwanted apps or files that may not severely damage, disable, or commandeer one's computer but do compromise system performance in various ways (such as by running activity-monitoring processes in the background, or popping up ads at regular intervals) is **malware**—a broad category of undesirable software that includes such subcategories as viruses, spyware (monitoring software), and adware (advertisement-serving software).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Benign virus no harmful for your computer system, because this is prank virus. But create some disturbance for user. This virus try to display some greeting text on your screen, and create clicking sound when pressing on famous celebrities' cake day.

Comment: The answer “**benign** virus” was given years ago.  Please don’t post a new answer just to say that you approve of or agree with another answer.  And the question doesn’t ask for *examples,* so this is not an answer.